# Git Staged - It have file history?

Tags: git, version-control

I am newbie in Git. And I really HATE use the command line, so I am using SmartGit.

I have some newbie question about the stage of git.

- The correct work-flow is : `stage -> commit -> synchronize`. With local commit I have the history of the file. But, with stage, I didn't have it? Like this case use:

  - I staged a fix. Then a work for a long time and save this in another staged process. But I want to go back to first staged. I can do this? Or I lost this history?
- Staged is just like a ROM (read only memory), so I can rewrite all file and the olds are lost?
- Why Stage is good thing to do? What I have in it that Commit don't have?

Comment: You can probably configure SmartGit to always commit all your changes (all changes in tracked files to be more exact).  In command line it would be `git commit -a` (with **-a** option).

Answer (score 8):

The reason the stage area exists is so that you can prepare your commit. For example, if you made unrelated changes to two different files, or different parts of the same file, you can stage only one of them, commit, then stage the other one and commit that (with different commit message).

Regarding your specific questions:

Because stage is there just for preparing your commit, it's not versioned itself. So, yeah, once you stage another version, the old one is lost (it might technically still exist as an object in the repository, but it's not easy to get to it).

And it's nothing like ROM, since you can write to it.

Note: The staging area is also used during a merge, so preparing your commit is not the only use. But it's the main one from the user's point of view.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want keep the versions of your stages in the index, you need to issue a commit.
- If you later want to merge the last commit and the new changes in the index you can use `git commit --amend` or `git commit;git rebase --interactive HEAD^^`
- The git index is not ROM. It will be modified by doing a `git reset` or `git add`.
- The git index is a great feature. It lets you create a commit from a partial set of the current changes. If you don't want to use it you do not have to. You can basically skip the index by commit code with `git commit --all`, as long as the files you modified are already tracked by git. For any new files, you can add then before the commit with `git add --all`

Answer (score 0):

The 'Staging area / Index' has two uses. One is for 'hiding' all the temporary files during merging, I'm sure you will come to that later. Its other role, which for the new user is a prime roll, is that is a place to prepare all your work before you commit. Getting the visualisation right makes quite a difference!

What is different is that it is kept distinct from your working directory. It is almost like an "out box" filing tray, my other visualisation is that of a 'storyboard' wall that you may see in films about magazine creation.

When you `add` files to the staging area you place them in the out-box / on the story board, and there they stay until you take them down / move them out.

When you `commit` the system (git) takes a proper copy of your staging area and places that in the repo, with your commit message. The storyboard wall still has everything on it until you change it - such as `add`, `rm` (remove), (swap to a different) `branch`, etc.

Once you have that visualisation you should find it much easier.