# How to know the different of change in git

Tags: git

I have file A.text with value 'a' and I did modify and change it to 'b'

with which command in git I can find the value before the change

also lets assume that I stage the file 
and now I change it again to 'b2'

How I can find the value 'a' ?

I need it only in the stage part of index part meaning I did change without stage I want to find the old value , now I stage and I did change for the file without commit

Comment: Try `git help diff` in the console or read the online documentation of [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Comment: maybe git diff but I want to get only the content of the old file and not the new

Comment: Add '--word-diff' to your diff command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Unstaged

```
git diff <filename>
```

This should show you all the additions/deletions to that file in the unstaged hunk of the file. Your old value i.e "a" should come in the deletions in file and new value "b" should come under additions to file.

For the staged hunk

```
git diff --cached <filename>
```

This will show you all the additions/deletions in the staged hunk.

That is all there is to this.

Answer (score 0):

`git diff` between the commit with the "a" value, and your latest change ?

Documentation : http://alx.github.io/gitbook/3_comparer_les_commits_-_git_diff.html

Comment: but I didn't do any commit just change the file and maybe stage it

Comment: Oh, you want the staged history then ?

Comment: There is no stage history I think. I found this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289035/git-staged-it-have-file-history

Comment: I want to change file and then to find the change then the second option is to stage the file and do another change